# Qt5: Обращение к данным в QVector для записи данных

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть класс (который по сути своей структура и далее я буду называть его именно так):

```
class GoodPosition
{
    int GSID; //Good or Service ID
    int Amount;
    double Price;
    int DealID; // Link to Basket ID
    int NumOfCell;//number of position in current basket
/*Далее идут конструкторы и геттеры, но их я опустил, дабы не мешались*/
}
```

Эта структура лежит в векторе QVector Goods

```
QVector<GoodPosition> * Goods = new QVector<GoodPosition>();
```

Мне необходимо обратиться к элементу вектора по индексу и к полю структуры для того, чтобы изменить это поле. 
Я делаю это так:

```
    void CheckDublicates()// данный метод пробегает по исходному списку и уничтожает дубликатные объекты, объединяя их в один. 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Goods->count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < Goods->count(); j++)
            {
                if (Goods->at(i).GSID == Goods->at(j).GSID)
                {
                  //  this->Goods->at(i).Amount = this->Goods->at(i).Amount + this->Goods->at(j).Amount;
                    this->Goods->at(i).Amount = addAmount(this->Goods->at(i), this->Goods->at(j));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Естественно, такая конструкция не работает. Это, как я понял, потому что at(i) возвращает нам константу и даёт работать только с константными методами.

Вопрос: Как изменить данные в ячейке структуры, которая лежит в QVector???

Comment: `Goods->operator[](i).Amount` Или храните Goods на стеке (`QVector<GoodPosition> Goods; ... Goods[i].Amount=...`)

Comment: Первый вариант мне подошёл больше, Оформите ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно словам @vegorov, для того, чтобы обратиться к ячейке на запись в `QVector` нужно вместо `at(i)` использовать `operator[](i).`